# not only does he learn English, he learn French too

Tags: sentence-construction

Is "he learn French too" grammatical? Should it be "he learns French too"?

> And not only does he learn English, he learn French too.

Source: English sentence making practice by me.

Comment: Yes, he **learns**, as normal.

Comment: [English sentence being practiced by me. Please correct yours. Thanks.] I do not understand why you are doing not only/too, when you are having trouble with basic verb forms.

Comment: @ Lambie:  Do you mean that I should have used "not only...but (also)..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"he learns French too" is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Not only does he learn English, he learns French too.

*General wording*

We would be more likely to say "Not only is he learning English, he is learning French too" or "Not only does he study English, he studies French too".

*Learn* v *Learns*

In the first clause ("Not only does he learn English"), "learn" is used because the auxiliary dummy verb "do" has been introduced (as is required by the inversion of a non-modal).  "He does learn" has no "-s" on the "learn", because the auxiliary "do" governs a bare infinitive.

In the second clause, there is no "does", so "learns" must be inflected with the "-s" ending.